# How to cleanly use Angular Routing w/ CSS grid

Tags: html, css, angular, css-grid

I have a pretty basic layout in `<app-root>`:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'UI';
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.component.css**

```
:host {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 63px 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    grid-template-areas:
      "navbar"
      "main"
}

app-navbar {
    grid-area: navbar;
}

routing-outlet {
    grid-area: main;
}
```

The issue that I'm having is that whatever html template is loaded by the routing module is being treated like a 3rd template on the page, meaning that the `<routing-module>` tag is taking the entire `1fr`, instead of the target template, and then the target template is loaded as a 3rd row, which is wrapped on the bottom border of the viewport.

I have a workaround, but it seems hack-y

```
grid-template-rows: 63px 0 1fr;
```

Is there a better/more-standard approach to this?

Comment: Please, is it possible to create online code example with layout pattern you use? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

better practice will be put `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` into `<div class="router-wrapper"></div>` and style that div like you did with `routing-module`. So most likely it could be:

```
.router-wrapper {
    grid-area: main;
}
```

Anyway you did little mistake with styling `routing-module`, because there is `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` tag in your template, not `routing-module`.

Comment: Oh wow, that was more obvious than I was expecting. Thanks for the feedback. I edited the code above to fix the `</router-outlet>` tag in the css